# Is it possible to retrieve latest version number of a device driver with C# alone?

Tags: c#, driver, wmi

I'm currently creating a program that detects the graphics card device as well as the version of the driver by using `Win32_VideoController` WMI class. I managed to get the name and the driver version as well as the OS version(from a different WMI class).

I basically need the latest driver info online for the specific device to alert the end user that they should update the specific driver. So far, I just have the above information.

I thought about using a string with the date of the current driver against the date of the more updated driver to alert the user. But, I'm sure there must be other ways of doing this that is more robust, where I can automatically get what the latest version or date the latest driver is on?